# What is the likely plan to deorbit the ISS given its size and shape?

Tags: iss, reentry

The ISS is nearing its final years and [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31363/how-exactly-will-the-iss-die-in-2025) spurred me to ask a follow up.

Let's say that the various countries grab whatever equipment/modules they provided in assembly and the ISS is geared to perform the retrograde burn and eventually splash down in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean. Is there (or would there be) a plan to disassemble the station to smaller "chunks" before reentry?

My armchair aeronautics engineering advice would be to disassemble the station and have several known entities reentering rather than deorbiting the whole station and have it break up into several unknown entities. Is that a reasonable/feasible plan or does it not really matter since the ocean is huge and all of the dangerously-moving debris will be confined to a safe area?

Comment: During a reentry the ISS will be dissambled anyway. Hopefully all parts wiil splash down in the ocean far away from any coast or island. If the ISS is dissambled before deorbiting you need the ability to control each part's deorbit. A lot of deorbit control units should be mounted before.

Comment: The Pacific would be a *way* easier target than the Atlantic...

Comment: Welcome to Space! Here are some related questions and answer you may also find interesting 
[Why is NASA planning to deorbit the ISS instead of reusing its newer modules, like the Russians will?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8514/12102) as well as [Why does the ISS have to be destroyed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24382/12102) and also [Why would extra fuel be needed to de-orbit the ISS (if it comes to that)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24354/12102)

Comment: @DJohnM The plan is for a reentry footprint that crosses the Indian Ocean, passing south of Australia and NZ, into the South Pacific -- a safe target region almost half the circumference of the Earth in length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This overview of the [2010 version of the ISS end-of-life disposal plan](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/578543main_asap_eol_plan_2010_101020.pdf) makes no mention of deliberately breaking up the station.

Because a substantial propulsive maneuver is being used to control the time and location of reentry (over the Indian and South Pacific oceans, rather than the Atlantic, as it happens), there would be no safe time window in which to dismantle the ISS. There would be less than an hour between end of the burn (which has to be done to the whole station at once) to the beginning of reentry.

Comment: Any idea what the delta-V would be (just a ballpark is kosher)?

Comment: My back-of-the-envelope estimate was ~50m/s. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24357/195

Comment: 50m/s doesn't seem too bad, but I'll admit that my KSP skills are a bit rusty as it's been a hot minute since I last played. :)